# Excel - Data Model - Relationship between Tables Not Working

Tags: excel

I've tried to find a solution to this problem on the web, however I can't seem to find it. It may be because I'm not searching by the correct phrasing, because it's also hard to describe. Regardless, I'm hoping someone out there can help.

## Situation

I have an Excel Document that I was given by a co-worker and it has a table within it. It has a lot of data on it, however for the sake of this example lets say it looks like this:

```
 Employee ID          Date Hired
 -----------          ----------
 1                    1/9/2019
 2                    5/4/2016
 3                    6/10/2017
 4                    3/8/2019
```

I want to pull additional data from SQL and connect the two tables, so the actions I took were:

1. Confirmed the Employee ID Column was formatted as a Number
2. Added the table to the data model
3. Added a new Query to the workbook that pulled in the data I wanted to add. Loaded as "Connection Only" but also "Added to Data Model". Let's pretend that table looked like this:

```
     Employee ID          Name                 Email
     -----------          ----------           --------------
     1                    Anthony              Anthony@company.com
     2                    Josh                 Josh@company.com
     3                    Jay                  Jay@company.com
     4                    Shane                Shane@company.com
     5                    Paul                 Paula@company.com
     6                    Steve                Steve@company.com
```

4. From the "Data" tab I opened "Manage Data Model" and confirmed both tables were included.
5. Confirmed that the "Employee ID" column on both tables were classified as Data type "Whole Number"
6. Switched to Diagram view and created a new relationship between the two tables by dragging the Employee ID from one table to the other.

Note, the relationship is formatted as:

[Original Table] * ----- 1 [Query Table]

However neither has any duplication's of the Employee ID field, which I have confirmed.

## Issue

I now want to create a Pivot table to slice the data (it makes more sense with the real tables).

1. I create a new Pivot table, and on the right hand side I see both the Original table and the Query table.
2. I pull Name Column from the Query table into the Rows Area
3. I pull the Date Hired Column from the Original table into the Rows Area, below the Name Column

**What I expect to see:**

```
Anthony
     1/9/2019
Josh
     5/4/2016
Jay
     6/10/2017
Shane
     3/8/2019
Paul
Steve
```

**What I actually see:**

```
Anthony
     1/9/2019
     5/4/2016
     6/10/2017
     3/8/2019
Josh
     1/9/2019
     5/4/2016
     6/10/2017
     3/8/2019
Jay
     1/9/2019
     5/4/2016
     6/10/2017
     3/8/2019
Shane
     1/9/2019
     5/4/2016
     6/10/2017
     3/8/2019
Paul
     1/9/2019
     5/4/2016
     6/10/2017
     3/8/2019
Steve
     1/9/2019
     5/4/2016
     6/10/2017
     3/8/2019
```

Essentially it can not identify which one belongs to whom, and so it lists all the dates under everyone.

Given that I've already verified that they're the same data type and that there are matching numbers on each table, can anyone clarify why this might be happening?

Thank you in advance for your help!!!

Comment: are you adding the columns from the tables of the Data Model? (they have a yellow icon)

Comment: Only the Query has a yellow Icon next to it, it looks like a little database, so I just assumed it meant it was a database connection.

The options for the pivot table are as follows:
Original Table: looks like a calendar with a gray top
Query: looks like a calendar with a gray top and a gold database next to it
A 3rd table that is in the excel but that I didn't add to the database: looks like a calendar with a white top

Comment: Ok if you're using the ones with the database icon, you're right. Try to check the direction of the relationship see this article: http://tinylizard.com/power-pivot-relationships/

Comment: Unfortunately that does not seem to be the problem.

In this case, I am treating the original table as the "Many" table and the query table as the "One table"; however it may be worth noting that neither table currently has any duplication of the employee ID value, so I could probably do it either way and I have tried it both ways.

Answer (score 1):

You are currently viewing all the dates in each employee because you haven't added a field (column) into the values of the pivot table. In your example, add "Employee ID" from the "query table" (or the table that has the dates)

Comment: Unfortunately this also did not work. However when I tested this new angle it did pop up with a yellow box saying that it needed a relationship. I clicked create relationship in that yellow box and connected the Employee ID's and it said that it couldn't do it because it would create a circular relationship?

Comment: That may be because I already had created the relationship in the data model

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing a similar issue with the relationship between a date table and my original data table. What worked for me was to change the direction of the relationship. Create the relationship by dragging the date column in your data table to the date column in your date table. This way, you will see the entity-relationship having a 1 on the the date table to a many on the data table.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).